# Short story with physics professor who "brings back the dead" (Asimov or Bradbury?)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There is a physics professor who, one day, gets drunk and starts a conversation with an English teacher saying that he can bring back the dead. I believe he said he tried... Shakespeare? Whoever it was, the professor said that he/she wanted to know how the future was going. I also vaguely remember the professor saying that he put the person he brought back from the dead in a class about themself and they were flunked!

I'm 80% sure that this is either a Ray Bradbury or Isaac Asimov work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is [The Immortal Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Immortal_Bard) by Asimov:

> The physics professor, Dr. Phineas Welch, has gotten himself slightly drunk and begins speaking with Scott Robertson, a young English teacher. Welch announces, "I can bring back the spirits of the illustrious dead." [...] "So," he continues, "I tried Shakespeare." [...]
>
> Eventually, Welch says, he enrolled Shakespeare in a night school class on Shakespeare's plays—taught, as it happens, by Robertson. At this point, Robertson begins to become genuinely worried. He recalls a bald man with an unusual accent, and starts to doubt whether Welch's story was all alcoholic fantasy. Timidly, he asks Welch what happened, and the physicist explodes with anger. Shakespeare had been humiliated, he says, and Welch had to send him back to 1600: "You poor simpleton, you flunked him!"